# Normalizr create result for single enity

Tags: redux, normalizr

I am using Normalizr to have the same response shape from different API endpoints.

```js
const post = new Schema('posts');
const posts = arrayOf('post');

const listResponse = [
  {id: 1, text: 'post one'},
  {id: 2, text: 'post two'},
];
normalize(listResponse, posts);

/*  
{
  entities: {
    posts: {
      1: {id: 1, text: 'post one'},
      2: {id: 2, text: 'post two'}
    }
  },
  result: [1, 2]
}
*/


const singleResponse = {id: 1, text: 'post one'};
normalize(singleResponse, post);

/*
{
  entities: {
    posts: {
      1: {id: 1, text: 'post one'}
    }
  },
  result: 1
}
*/
```

Then I would like to treat normalized response no matter how it came.

But the thing is that for a single item I am getting `result: 1` instead of array `result: [1]` and it cause some issues in my later code.

Now I have to normalize `result` to array manually, but maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my application, I used two different actions for this case, `FETCH_POST` and `FETCH_POSTS` accordingly.

But if you have some issues with it, you can use a little hack:

```js
const singleResponse = {id: 1, text: 'post one'};
normalize([singleResponse], posts);
```

When normalizing single post item, we can simply wrap it to array and normalize it as array of posts.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't want to have two actions, which are doing exactly the same. It makes my reducer to be twice shorter.